# how to define a list of file objects in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, object

for defining a single file object pointing to a file, in python we just write:

```
f = open ('file_name.txt','wb')
```

I wanted to know in case of several (lets say 50) files, how could I create an array (or in python terminology list) of 50 file objects, each pointing to a text file with the same index in its name?

Comment: I have some doubts as to why you would think this is a good idea

Comment: I'd be interested to know what the intended application is, or whether this question simply came from curiosity. But I can think of applications where it might be a good idea (such as splitting a file into multiple files, each of which corresponded to an upper- or lower-case letter of the alphabet).

Comment: @holdenweb It could be useful for logging that needs to be separately categorised. But I'm unsure when it'd be beneficial to do that by list instead of a dictionary.

Comment: Well, we can all imagine use cases, can't we? But are they relevant to the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lists in Python are just a collection of references, they could refer to anything you want including a file object.

```
files = [
           open("file1.txt",'wb')
           open("file2.txt",'wb')
           open("file3.txt",'wb')
           ...
        ]
```

Depending on how you want to gather them up you can likely use a generator. For example

```
files = [open("file_{}".format(x),'wb') for x in range(12)]
```

Or if you wanted to get all the files from a folder:

```
files = [open(file, 'wb') for file in os.listdir(yourFolder)]
```

Be careful with opening too many though as that could become a memory issue.

Comment: Less of a memory issue than running out of available file descriptors.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Guilaume's answer, you could also use list comprehension (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)) like this:

```
myFiles = [open('file'+str(i)+'.txt', 'wb') for i in range(3)]

myFiles[0].write('hello world')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to create a list of files:

```
myfiles=[]
for i in range(3):
    f = open ('file'+str(i),'wb')
    myfiles.append(f)

myfiles[0].write("hello world")
```

Answer (score 0):

Files are objects like everything else in Python. So just as you can put a string into a list `lst` with

```
lst[n] = "value"
```

or

```
lst.append(value)
```

so, when you understand the the `open()` function returns a file object, you can put a file into a list with

```
lst[n] = open(filename, 'wb')
```

or

```
lst.append(open(filename, 'wb')
```

So to create a list of open files you can simply use the last example in a loop that computes filenames (though you could just as easily iterate over a list of filenames if you already have them).

```
file_list = []
for i in range(50):
    filename = "file{}.txt".format(i)
    file_list.append(open(filename, 'wb'))
```

This can be achieved rather more compactly (but also rather more opaquely) in a single expression using a list comprehension. Tastes differ.

```
file_list = [open("file{}.txt".format(i), 'wb') for i in range(50)]
```

While having 50 files open is unlikely to cause problems on a modern operating system, you should be aware that there are upper limits on the resources you can demand of the operating system.